# En-/decrypt "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

Could anyone tell me how I would decrypt data (using Java) that has been encrypted with this PHP function?

#### PHP Code

```
    public function pad($data, $blocksize = 16) {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize);
        return $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }
    public function decryptECB($data) {
        return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::BLOB_ENCRYPTION_KEY, self::pad($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    }
    public function encryptECB($data) {
        return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::BLOB_ENCRYPTION_KEY, self::pad($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    }
```

I have tried most of the things here but most of them are without padding and even when I add padding they don't work.

Edit 1:

(From PHP)

The input looks like this: http://pastebin.com/2cyig9nh

Key is this:

```
M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4
```

And output is this: http://pastebin.com/XcA50UGH

(The Java code)

```
public class Mcrypt {

private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
private Cipher cipher;

private String SecretKey = "M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4";

public Mcrypt() {
    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
    if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");
    byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec );
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
}

public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception {
    if (code == null || code.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");
    byte[] decrypted = null;

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec );
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(new Base64().decode(code.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return decrypted;
}

private static String padString(String source) {
    char paddingChar = ' ';
    int size = 16;
    int x = source.length() % size;
    int padLength = size - x;
    for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
        source += paddingChar;
    }
    return source;
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be using `ECB` mode.

Comment: I know but the thing I'm sending to uses it I need too

Comment: Originally I answered this, then I realise my answer was contained in your title. Please can you post the Java code you've tried? I'm confused why `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` wouldn't work. Please also include sample input data (e.g. your key and plaintext) and sample output data (e.g. your ciphertext) for your PHP function.

Comment: I added the in- and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding and decoding to Base64 in your Java code, but your PHP code does not seem to perform any encoding/decoding whatsoever. This seems to be confirmed by what you posted on Pastebin. If you want to use strings instead of bytes - bytes are the only input accepted by modern ciphers - then you should make sure that the (character) encoding is correct on both sides. If you just want to use bytes, don't decode the binary in Java - the input is already in bytes, not text.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot too understand things